# npm doesn't start propperly, Cannot find module 'worker_threads

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-start

I've got following version in `node: v10.24.0` and following version in `npm: 6.14.11.`
Now when I want to start my Angular frontend with the command ng serve there will be thrown following error code:

> ng serve

An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'worker_threads'

See `"/tmp/ng-10r9yq/angular-errors.log"` for further details.

> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! syscall spawn
>
> npm ERR! file sh
>
> npm ERR! errno ENOENT
>
> npm ERR! frontend@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
>
> npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.0.0 start script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
> additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     /home/.npm/_logs/2021-08-10T09_38_36_059Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

You can try updating your Node Version to 14.0.0 or higher and it should work as desired